# Nil check in `||`, `!a || a.method` can't be done with multiple variables

Tags: crystal-lang

For example, if we want to check an array is either nil or empty, we can write as follows:

```
if !a || a.empty?
    puts "nil or empty!"
end
#-> OK
```

however, if we want to check two arrays in the same way, an error occurs:

```
if !a || !b || a.empty? || b.empty?
    puts "nil or empty!"
end
#-> Error, `undefined method 'empty?' for Nil`
#          in the expression `a.empty?`
```

Swapping the position of `!b` and `a.empty?` doesn't help, but different place is pointed to as an error:

```
if !a || a.empty? || !b || b.empty?
    puts "nil or empty!"
end
#-> Still error, `undefined method 'empty?' for Nil`
#                but this error is in the expression `b.empty?`
```

Why in this (multiple variable's) case compiler can't infer that `a` and `b` are non-nil when `a.empty?` and `b.empty?` are called, respectively?

The whole reproducible code is following.

```
def foo (flag)
    if flag
        [] of Int32
    else
        nil
    end
end

# note, foo returns `Array(T) | Nil`
a = foo(true)
b = foo(true)

if !a || a.empty?
    puts "nil or empty!"
end
#-> OK

if !a || !b || a.empty? || b.empty?
    puts "nil or empty!"
end
#-> Error, `undefined method 'empty?' for Nil`
#          in the expression `a.empty?`

if !a || a.empty? || !b || b.empty?
    puts "nil or empty!"
end
#-> Still error, `undefined method 'empty?' for Nil`
#                but this error is in the expression `b.empty?`
```

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into writing the question, but [you don't need the trailing "Thank you"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I understand. I removed "Thank you" from my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like a compiler bug.

But you can just put the conditions in parenthesis to make it work: `(!a || a.empty?) || (!b || b.empty?)`

Comment: Blaming the compiler is so easy... (but it indeed works)

Comment: Nope, it's not a bug. My answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug.

```
a || b || c || d
```

is parsed as:

```
(((a || b) || c) || d)
```

so in your example you have:

```
!a || !b || a.empty? || b.empty?
```

which means it's

```
(((!a || !b) || a.empty?) || b.empty?)
```

so from:

```
!a || !b
```

you can't deduce anything about `a` or `b`.

It works if you add parentheses:

```
if !a || (!b || (a.empty? || b.empty?))
```

Comment: The boolean expression short circuits if the left side argument `!a || !b` is true. Therefore `b.empty?` *can* only be evaluated if both `a` and `b` are truthy, i.e. not `nil`. From a logical point this should be solid.
The question is if the Crystal compiler should be able to deduce that or not.

Comment: With that `or` you can't deduce anything about a or b. I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Check the parentheses I put, the whole or expression is in one, and you can't deduce anything from it.

Comment: You said from `!a || !b` we can't deduce anything, but if `!a || !b` is falsey, we can deduce both `a` and `b` are truthy. The suceeding expression will only be evaluated in that case because of short-circuit evaluation, so we could assume `a` and `b` are both non-Nil after `!a || !b`, I think.